# How do I change the language via a terminal?

Tags: command-line, language-support

Using system settings I changed my language to Arabic and deleted the English language from the settings.  Then the computer lagged and it logged out - now I can't log back in because the login is in Arabic.

So is there a way to default my language via terminal, default the login password language, or login via terminal which is still in English.  I only have access to guest and a terminal.

---

I changed the pasword to something that could be translated into arabic http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword - then loged in and used system settings to default.

Answer (score 61):

Edit two files:

1. `sudoedit /etc/default/locale`:

   ```
   LANG="en_US"
   LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
   ```
2. `sudoedit ~/.pam_environment`:

   ```
   LANG=en_US
   LANGUAGE=en_US
   ```

Logout and Login or Reboot.

Comment: Nano is also installed by default. :-)

Comment: If you want to understand what changing these variables means: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Comment: Also need `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: If using KDE, you might want to check `~/.KDE/env/setlocale.sh` too, as it might conflict.

Comment: This also works for "Bash on Ubuntu" on Windows 10.

Comment: @hlcs You shouldn't set `LC_ALL` in `/etc/default/local`, and definitely shouldn't need it.  `LC_ALL` prevents you from using fine grained control of `LC_*` vars.  Users / apps would need to `unset LC_ALL` to do this.  On the other hand `LANG` sets the defaults for all the `LC_*` vars that have not been set explicitly.  If `LANG` is not working for you then you need to trace through your profile and find out what is overriding it.

Comment: @couling - After NOT setting LC_ALL, I got these errors: https://pastebin.com/AgerQC7q -- On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - and while using apt to dist-upgrade.

Comment: @Shiki `If LANG is not working for you then you need to trace through your profile and find out what is overriding it.`  But looking at your error you may need too look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-to-fix-a-locale-setting-warning-from-perl

Comment: Works like a charm on Raspbian too (`sudo raspi-config` just caused more problems than good)

Answer (score 5):

In order to get back to English, I had to change my locale in 3 places:

1. `/etc/default/locale`

   by running this command:

   ```
   $ sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE= LC_MESSAGES= LC_COLLATE= LC_CTYPE=
   ```
2. `~/.config/plasma-localerc` and `~/.config/plasma-locale-settings.sh`

   By going to my KDE settings / Regional Settings / Language

And reboot.

Comment: I only had to run `echo export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 |  sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this interactively using `dpkg-reconfigure`:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locale
```

and follow the steps on the next screens.

After that, logout/login again and/or reboot.