# How to change environment variable LANGUAGE globally in kde

Tags: kubuntu, kde, language-support, locale

My objective is to change globally the `LANGUAGE` var to `en_US.UTF-8`. Currently it is `en:he:en`.

When issuing command `locale` I get this output:

```
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en:he:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I can change `LANGUAGE` for bash in `.bashrc` with `export`. It works afterwards for GTK programs I start from the shell.

`export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`

But that does not hold for programs I start from Kde menu or alt-f2.The menu of any GTK program I start from there appears in the second language instead of English.

- I have investigated and changed /etc/default/locale but that did not help.
- I have tried gnome-language-selector. The same result.
- I have tried to change KDE system settings -> locale. No help.

Where does the setting `LANGUAGE=en:he:en` comes from ?

Comment: Found an answer in this question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/565768/where-is-the-language-environment-variable-set. So my question is a duplicate. The author of the question suggest changing ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you found *where* to change it. However, a few things:

- `en_US.UTF-8` is not a [valid value](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#The_LANGUAGE_priority_list) in the LANGUAGE variable. You probably just want `en`.
- I noticed that LANG has the value `en_US`. That enables latin1 encoding, which you don't likely want. Should be `en_US.UTF-8`.
- If LANG is set correctly, you should not set the LC_ALL variable, because it effectively disables all GUIs for managing languages/locales.