# Can't change language back to English in Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, language-support, kde5

## Problem:

In Settings -> Regional Settings, I added language Marathi and Hindi to see how it works and what it translates(I know Marathi, and Hindi). After I rebooted, the language was changed to Marathi. Now, I wanted to revert back to English, as that is the language I am used to in handling the computer. But, as I click on the Add Languages... button, nothing happens, no dialogue box appears. Because of this I am not able to change language to any other except those present as Added Languages.

## Steps to reproduce:

Go to Settings -> Regional Settings -> Click Add Languages... -> Add Hindi - हिंदी (or Marathi - मराठी, others might not give same results, don't know) -> Click Apply -> Restart Computer -> Go to तंत्र विन्यास (प्रणाली संयोजना in case of Marathi) -> Regional Settings -> Click Add Languages...

## What I have tried:

1. [Where is the LANGUAGE environment variable set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565768/where-is-the-language-environment-variable-set)
2. [locale: Reset lost settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2855/locale-reset-lost-settings)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387199/how-to-change-the-language-locale-for-the-ubuntu-terminal
4. https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-change-to-your-native-language-on-ubuntu-17-10/
5. https://www.shellhacks.com/linux-define-locale-language-settings/
6. [Some menus are in Chinese/Japanese!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130649/some-menus-are-in-chinese-japanese)

## Additional information:

System Settings is crashing sometimes.

#### Crash log:

```
Application: प्रणाली संयोजना (systemsettings5), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f395cdb46c0 (LWP 3574))]

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f393b5ef700 (LWP 3583)):
#0  __GI___libc_read (nbytes=16, buf=0x7f393b5eeb20, fd=18) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
#1  __GI___libc_read (fd=18, buf=0x7f393b5eeb20, nbytes=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:24
#2  0x00007f395f16a410 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f395f1236cf in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f395f123ba0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f395f123d1c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f3961944063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f39618ef5bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f396173a2c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f3960a5cef5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#10 0x00007f396173b612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007f395fbbb182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#12 0x00007f39613ceb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f3946909700 (LWP 3582)):
#0  0x00007f395f16e809 in g_mutex_lock () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007f395f123b00 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f395f123d1c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f3961944063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f39618ef5bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f396173a2c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f3960a5cef5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#7  0x00007f396173b612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f395fbbb182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#9  0x00007f39613ceb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f3950a27700 (LWP 3580)):
#0  0x00007f39613c2729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f3940004a30, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f395f123bf6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f395f123d1c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f3961944063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f39618ef5bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f396173a2c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f3960a5cef5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#7  0x00007f396173b612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f395fbbb182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#9  0x00007f39613ceb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f3953cb5700 (LWP 3578)):
#0  futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x560f3a7f1b2c) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
#1  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, mutex=0x560f3a7f1ad8, cond=0x560f3a7f1b00) at pthread_cond_wait.c:502
#2  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x560f3a7f1b00, mutex=0x560f3a7f1ad8) at pthread_cond_wait.c:655
#3  0x00007f39582fc36b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
#4  0x00007f39582fc0d7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
#5  0x00007f395fbbb182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#6  0x00007f39613ceb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f395a806700 (LWP 3577)):
#0  __GI___libc_read (nbytes=16, buf=0x7f395a805b10, fd=7) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
#1  __GI___libc_read (fd=7, buf=0x7f395a805b10, nbytes=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:24
#2  0x00007f395f16a410 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f395f1236cf in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f395f123ba0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f395f123d1c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f3961944063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f39618ef5bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f396173a2c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f3961bbc565 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#10 0x00007f396173b612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007f395fbbb182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#12 0x00007f39613ceb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f395bd33700 (LWP 3576)):
#0  0x00007f39613c2729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f395bd32c68, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f395fb78917 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007f395fb7a53a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007f395c7066a8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007f396173b612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f395fbbb182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#6  0x00007f39613ceb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f395cdb46c0 (LWP 3574)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  0x0000560f42a72ff0 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f396191f718 in QObject::connect(QObject const*, char const*, QObject const*, char const*, Qt::ConnectionType) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f3960901f9c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#9  0x00007f39609022db in QV4::QObjectWrapper::wrap_slowPath(QV4::ExecutionEngine*, QObject*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#10 0x00007f396097f88c in QV4::ExecutionEngine::fromVariant(QVariant const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#11 0x00007f39608e02e5 in QV4::QQmlContextWrapper::virtualGet(QV4::Managed const*, QV4::PropertyKey, QV4::Value const*, bool*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#12 0x00007f396088648d in QV4::ExecutionContext::getProperty(QV4::String*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#13 0x00007f3960986d40 in QV4::Runtime::method_loadName(QV4::ExecutionEngine*, int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#14 0x00007f39397e80d8 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 3574) detached]
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: @DKBose I have added version of Kubuntu.

Comment: `localectl status` please.

Comment: @nobody I have done a clean install, so can't really say. Nevertheless, I think I successfully changed System Language to English (see `What I've tried` above), but it was Plasma's language that I couldn't change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Root cause:

When we add language via *System Settings > Regional Settings*, it is added as KDE Plasma's (Desktop Environment's) Language and not System Language. Hence, though System Language shows English (run `locale` in terminal), we still see our desktop in the language specified in Regional Settings.

This is also the reason why using

1. `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` or
2. `sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8` or
3. Putting `export LANG=en_US.utf8` in `~/.bashrc` and running `source ~/.bashrc`

doesn't effect the language setting set in Regional Setting.

## Solution:

Go to `~/.config/plasma-locale-settings.sh`, open it and ensure it contains following:

```
# Generated script, do not edit
# Exports language-format specific env vars from startkde.
# This script has been generated from kcmshell5 formats.
# It will automatically be overwritten from there.
# I am from India, hence en_IN, shouldn't matter much
export LANG=en_IN
export LANGUAGE=en_US
```

then, go to `~/.config/plasma-localerc`, open it and ensure it contains following:

```
[Formats]
LANG=en_IN

[Translations]
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

Shutdown the computer and start again. You should be back on English. If not, do let me know by comment :)

Comment: Horrible to have to edit a tucked away config file to get a human readable language. (translations to local languages are a freakshow.)

Answer (score 3):

I have the [Kubuntu backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=disco) enabled on my system and so I may have a more recent version of Plasma than provided by vanilla Kubuntu 19.04.

Operating System: Kubuntu 19.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.16.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.60.0
Qt Version: 5.12.2
Kernel Version: 5.0.0-23-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

---

When I opened *System Settings > Regional Settings > Language* for the first time, no languages were listed under *Configure Plasma Translations*. So I first added *American English* and then added *Hindi*. I tried to add *Marathi* as the third language and that caused a *System Settings* crash. So I stayed with just the two languages.

To switch languages, click on the row listing the language you want and then bring it to the top as shown:

[image]

The change of language needs a log out:

[image]

As you can see, the translations are partial. [The translation team](https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/translation) would appreciate help in this respect if you have the time to spare.

Comment: I hadn't added American English. Could you try to click `Add languages...` button when in Hindi language? If it's a bug, might as well state that on KDE forum. In any case, I did a clean install :) So, I am on English now.

Answer (score 1):

The default `locale` file location here:
**/etc/default**

Step 1: Install `nautilus-admin` then logOut and logIn.

Step 2: go to **/etc/default**.

Step 3: Right click on `locale` and ***Edit As Administrator***.

Edit `locale` file like this and save:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Done. Now log-out and log-in.

Comment: On Fedora you can also log in as root once and do that with the standard text editor.