# LANG is always local, ignores ~/.profile

Tags: bash

In my `~/.profile`, I have:

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

I think that was the Ubuntu default.

However, when I start a shell (e.g. Konsole), I get:

```
gz@gcomputer:~$ echo $LANG
de_DE.UTF-8
```

Even when I change my `~/.profile` to `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, I don't get a difference.

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: `UTF-8` encoding does not make any sense to the `C` locale. Also the best place to set `LANG` is `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: Konsole probably starts a non-login bash shell (which would therefore read ~/.bashrc rather than ~/.profile, I think?)

Comment: @heemayl `C.UTF-8` is fairly new but it does make sense.  See https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Proposals/C.UTF-8

Comment: @zwol ahhh.. didn't know about the proposal.. thanks..

Comment: Possibly there is some syntax error in your `~/.profile` which prevents it from being run correctly. You can check that with the command: `bash -n ~/.profile`

Answer (score 4):

[According to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/133324/527764) You should change language settings in `etc/default/locale` and `~/.pam_environment`, not in `~/.profile`

`etc/default/locale` is generated by `update-locale` so you do this to set `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` (the file also sets LANGUAGE)

```
update-locale LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

In ~/.pam_environment language settings look the same as in `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

and can be edited as desired. You have to log out and back in or use `source`:

**In general** you have to log out and log back in for changes made to `~/.profile` to take effect.

However, you can make them instant using `source`

```
source ~/.profile
```

**Example:**

I edit my ~/.profile to include:

```
export foo=bar
```

save and exit...

in a new shell:

```
$ echo $foo
```

(nothing)

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ echo $foo
bar
```

If nothing changed after logging out and back in, check that `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` do not exist (because, as mentioned by @ByteCommander, if they do exist, `~/.profile` is not sourced)

If either do exist, the best thing to do is probably to copy any commands from them into your `~/.profile` and rename them something like `~/.bash_profile_old` and `~/.bash_login_old`, so that `~/.profile` gets sourced (and you are not depending on bash being your shell)

If neither of them exist, it may be that `~/.profile` is still not getting sourced for some reason:

[See Eliah Kagan's answer here for more detail](https://askubuntu.com/a/532029/527764)

The suggested workaround is to use... `~/.pam_environment`

Comment: `# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists.`

Answer (score 1):

For reasons too tedious to get into here, bash has *several* per-user configuration files.  The most important two are `.profile` and `.bashrc`.  Bash reads *one or the other* of them on every startup, but not both, depending on conditions which are too confusing for me to bother remembering.

What I do instead is put everything meaningful in `.profile`, plus an extra line reading

```
profile_loaded=t
```

and then I have a `.bashrc` consisting just of

```
if test -z "$profile_loaded"; then
    . ~/.profile
fi
```

If you adopt this approach, it is important to make sure that everything `.profile` does is *idempotent*, which is a fancy word for "doing this more than once is the same as doing it only once.  One easy way to accomplish that is to wrap the entire contents of `.profile` in a similar conditional:

```
if test -z "$profile_loaded"; then

    # ... all the actual work goes here ...

    profile_loaded=t
fi
```

(If you have files named `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login`, that confuses the issue further: I strongly recommend copying their contents into `.profile`, deleting them, and then cleaning up any duplication in `.profile`.)

Comment: Please note that `~/.profile` is sourced by lightdm on an Ubuntu desktop, so no, I don't think it's a good idea to have everything in `~/.profile`. For non-expert users I'd rather say: Stick to the default as far as possible.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson How can that possibly work? lightdm doesn't contain an entire implementation of Bourne shell language, does it?

Comment: No, but it makes use of it. Actually, since a couple of years (my fault) it depends on bash. At first hand I'm talking about `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session`.