# How do I change the date language in the terminal?

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, konsole

if I do an `ls -l`, I get output such as the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        93584 Apr 21  2017  zipsplit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        26624 Ott  5  2018  zjsdecode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         2206 Aww 23 11:24  zless
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         1842 Aww 23 11:24  zmore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         4553 Aww 23 11:24  znew
```

See where the date is... how do I change that to English?

I'm using Konsole on Kubuntu.

**Edit**: Output of `locale` as requested:

```
daniel@cassiopeia:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=mt_MT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

There is clearly a mixture of US-English and Maltese in there. How do I get rid of the Maltese and just keep English? Or, say, change it to UK English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the language via a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133318/how-do-i-change-the-language-via-a-terminal)

Comment: ^ that doesn't show how to change the language for dates, which is set by `LC_TIME`

Comment: Do you *only* want dates to be displayed in English, or are there other elements you want to be in English? Do you *always* want dates displayed in English, or just temporarily? Can you [edit] and give the output of `locale`?

Comment: @Zanna I just want everything to be in English. I've added the output of `locale` as requested.

Comment: Thanks! I think you'll be able to do this through Language Support settings. Sorry that I don't know what it looks like in Kubuntu... I also don't know how to do it properly by command line. Hopefully you will get an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming, from another question by you, that you're using Kubuntu 19.10. (This is somewhat important because some settings move around from one version to another.)

In Kubuntu 19.10 with the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) installed, I'm on

Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.17.2
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.62.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4

In this system, open *System Settings > Regional Settings*, and click on the *Formats* icon in the left panel. In the image below, I chose a time format setting for Malta from the dropdown next to *Time*, logged out and logged in again. On opening konsole, I see this

[image: Time format setting for Malta]

To change to something else, I just go through the process again, log out and log back in:

[image: Time format setting for UK]

---

One point to note is that just because you see something in the dropdown (in *System Settings > Regional Settings*) and can apparently choose it, that doesn't mean it's actually available.

To get `mt_MT.utf8` on my system, I had to "uncomment" the relevant entry in `/etc/locale.gen` and then run `sudo locale-gen`.

Comment: System Settings -> Regional Settings did it. I didn't have to install anything or touch any files.

Comment: @Gigi I had to in order to get mt_MT.utf8 on my system so I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

As rinzwind commented, you can change locale for the Whole terminal use.
As I guess, you just want to change the language for one command, sometimes only.

In that case, simply 'prefix' the command with a variable. It is command expansion.
See the bash manual : https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion

```
$ LANG=en_US.utf8 ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        93584 Apr 21  2017  zipsplit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        26624 Oct  5  2018  zjsdecode
(...)

$ LANG=en_US.utf8 gnome-control-center
# will start the gui with english language

$ GZIP=-9 tar cvzf /path/to/archive myarchive.tar.gz
# This will set max compression level (9) for gzip option in tar command
```

---

You can also create some aliases in your `.bashrc` in order to change locale language quickly :

```
# inside .bashrc
alias langen='LANG=en_US.utf8'
alias langne='LANG=ne_NP UTF-8'

# Then in a terminal
$ langen
$ ls -l
# get an output in  english
# then switch back to your preferred language
$ langne
```

---

Get enabled locales (installed locale languages) codes with `locale -a`.
Get avaiable locales with `cat /etc/locale.gen`
Enable a new one with `sudo locale-gen ne_NP UTF-8`

Comment: There is no indication that they want to change the language for one command. What they have said is that they want to change the language in which dates are displayed (in the terminal), for example when running `ls`. This is done in Language Support under Regional Formats IIRC

Comment: or by editing the locale settings, but not the ones the suggested duplicate mentions (here's a [screenshot from my Konsole on Xubuntu](http://i.imgur.com/ZunpZrx.png) - I'm using Konsole because it renders Tamil correctly, unlike other terminal emulators - I'm not using Kubuntu so I don't know how to answer this question properly)

Comment: @Zanna :  Language Support under Regional Formats has more than 'Terminal' as focus. That's why i suggested the command expansion. I guess you will understand that i well understood the question. Kind of I had myself in the past.

Comment: @Zanna is right. I don't want to change it just for one command (why would I do that?).